# list comprehension - how to map strings as integers?

Tags: python, string, list, numbers

I have a simple task of creating a matrix of squared size n, such as through the diagonal I have a string of zeros, and then growing outwards numbers with +1. I have achieved the result by doing so:

```
def abs(num):
    if num >= 0:
        return num
    else:
        return -num
    
n = int(input())

matrix = [[f'{abs(x-y)}' for y in range(n)] for x in range (n)]

for n in range(n):
    map(int, matrix[n])
    print(matrix[n])
```

achieving the result as such:

```
['0', '1', '2', '3', '4']
['1', '0', '1', '2', '3']
['2', '1', '0', '1', '2']
['3', '2', '1', '0', '1']
['4', '3', '2', '1', '0']
```

however I need to get rid of apostrophes so my results look like this:

```
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
[1, 0, 1, 2, 3]
[2, 1, 0, 1, 2]
[3, 2, 1, 0, 1]
[4, 3, 2, 1, 0]
```

I have read that python interprets my results as strings, not integers and that's where the problem is coming from, but I tried to eradicate the problem and did not manage to. Anyone can spot where am I making a mistake?

Comment: Why do you explicitly, with extra code, create strings, if that's not what you want?

Comment: The answer by @Mureinik is right, but I also want to mention that `map()` returns a new list, which you're not assigning anywhere. It's not mutating its argument in place.

Comment: You use map to apply int to each row, and then... throw that input away because you don't use it. If you wanted to use map to solve the problem, it would be `matrix[n] = list(map(int, matrix[n]))`. But of course @Mureinik's answer is the way to go.

Comment: Just don't put quotes in the f-string if you don't want them... Also, why do you redefine `abs` which already exists as a builtin function and does the same (and a bit more)?

Comment: @joanis The `int(input())` and the `print` with parentheses rather suggest that they're using Python 3, not Python 2.

Comment: I would just like to point out that `abs` is already a built-in function; there's no need to define it separately.

Comment: @Manuel Is `map()` different between python 2 and 3? I didn't realize that. I was assuming Python 3 in my comment.

Comment: thank you everyone! I am kind-of blindly trying to reproduce lines from my university lectures so that's why I am making some mistakes here ;) Thanks everyone for help!

Comment: @joanis In Python 3 it returns an iterator instead of a list.

Comment: @Manuel Oh, I gotcha, you have to say list(map(...)) to have a list out of map, whereas in python 2 it returns a list.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You shouldn't format the calculation in a string. Remove the string formatting and you should be fine:

```py
matrix = [[abs(x-y) for y in range(n)] for x in range (n)]
```

Side note: Python has a built-in `abs` function, you don't need to re-implement it.

Answer (score 1):

First you are explicitly casting the values to string, so you shouldn't do that

```
matrix = [[abs(x-y) for y in range(n)] for x in range (n)]

for n in range(n):
    print(matrix[n])
```